# find max value after auto-filter

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Filter_Click()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
Dim key1 As String
key1 = InputBox("Type Script Name", "Title")
For k = 1 To j
With Worksheets(k)
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=key1
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="26-nov-15"
End With
Next k
End Sub

Sub Clear()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
For k = 1 To j
Worksheets(k).Range("A1").AutoFilter
Next k
End Sub
```

I am using above macros for filtering and to remove filter. Columns remains identical in all sheets. Currently I am using simple max function to find max value manually in all sheets after filtration. I will be more happy if macro will highlight max value row. Current picture is, in column D, have different text, such as CE and PE. In column L have numbers which we have to find maximum number. So match CE text from column D and find max value from column L. Again match PE text from column D and find max value from column L and highlight entire both rows. Lastly it should get undo when I run clear macro.

Answer (score 1):

As a sheet formula, you can use `=SUBTOTAL()`, e.g.

```
=SUBTOTAL(104;C3:C33)
```

With the type argument above 100 the function will act only on visible cells and hence only display the max of all displayed cells. You could display the "filtered max" somewhere in the header area of your sheet(s) ... I usually do it just above the column headings.

**Edit** ... VBA

let's do a SUB which receives a Range and marks the MAX value in that range ... a second Boolean parameter selects only visible rows or all rows to be marked ... a third Boolean parameter selects if you set or remove your color mark ... classical loop construct

```
Sub MarkMax(MyR As Range, OnlyVisible As Boolean, UnDo As Boolean)
Dim Idx As Integer, Tmp As Integer

    Idx = 2                                           ' first row to be compared against current MAX
    Tmp = 1                                           ' first value is first MAX (against better knowledge)

    Do While Idx <= MyR.Rows.Count

        If MyR(Idx, 1) > MyR(Tmp, 1) Then
            If (OnlyVisible And Not MyR(Idx, 1).EntireRow.Hidden) Or Not OnlyVisible Then
                Tmp = Idx                             ' capture index of new MAX
            End If
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1                                 ' advance list
    Loop

    With MyR(Tmp, 1).Interior
        If UnDo Then
            .Pattern = xlNone                         ' remove color
        Else
            .Pattern = xlAutomatic                    ' set color
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If

    End With


End Sub
```

You would call it as `MarkMax [L2:Lxxx], True, False` to set color on MAX of currently visible rows, and `MarkMax [L2:Lxxx], True, True` to clear the mark.

Comment: Thanks Mike for taking your time. I need vba code line inside above macro, so that it automatically do that work and highlight entire row.